# Which is more performant to render item list through useSelector?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I would like to get an item list and render a component for each item.

The item is a deep object like `{"id":1,"name":"cleaner","attributes":{"color":"red","size":"large"}}`.

Solution I: single useSelector in top level, pass props to child

```
const Child = (props) => {
  const { item } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{item.id}</div>
      <div>{item.name}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Parent = () => {
  const items = useSelector(state => state.items, shallowEqual);

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map(item => <Child key={item.id} item={item} />)}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Solution II: retrieve keys in top level, useSelector in Child to retrieve object

```
const Child = (props) => {
  const { itemId } = props;
  const item = useSelector(state => state.items.find(item => item.id === itemId) || {}, shallowEqual);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{item.id}</div>
      <div>{item.name}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Parent = () => {
  const itemIds = useSelector(state => state.items.map(item => item.id), shallowEqual);

  return (
    <div>
      {itemIds.map(id => <Child key={id} itemId={id} />)}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are already using redux, you don't have to deal with scenarios involving lifting state up.

In Solution II both Parent and Child are using `useSelector` which was minimized to just one call on Solution I, making, `Child` effectively a dumb component, which is a good thing.

I find reducing computation logic whenever possible a good thing. Solution II has more computation logic compared to Solution I, so I'd go with the latter.